# How to handle exception thrown in another thread in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

I am using a third party library and my android Application class is extending application class from that library. In the constructor of library application class a thread is starting up. Now in some scenario that thread is throwing NumberFormatException. How I can handle that exception thrown in thread of third party library inside my application. If I write below code in my application class onCreate method will it catch that exception.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("Exception caught"     " + e);

            }});
```

If I use static method `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` inside my code will it caught exception of other threads also or only application ui thread.

More info
I wrote a small program to test it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("Exception caught." + t.getName() + "     "
                        + e);
            }
        });
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

How it is catching exception of child thread in this case if setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler catch exception of thread in which it is called?

Comment: @pskink I have added more info in my question. Please check it.

Comment: if this method is static it is applied to Thread.currentThread()